ScrollViewReader not scrolling to list item on iOS 18
For a long list, I would like to scroll to a particular item when it appears. This works perfectly on iOS 17:
NavigationLink {
    ScrollViewReader { proxy in
        List {
            ForEach(sections, id: \.key) { section in
                SomeListItem(section: section)
                .id(section.key) // adding or removing this does not help.
            }
        }.onAppear {
            proxy.scrollTo(currentSection, anchor: .center)
        }
    }            
} label: {
    Image(systemName: "filemenu.and.selection").padding()
}.buttonStyle(DefaultButtonStyle())


However, it does nothing on iOS 18. Has anyone been able to get around this?

Works for me when running on an iPhone 16 simulator with iOS 18.0 (Xcode 16.0).

@BenzyNeez thank you for confirming. I do have this list in a NavigationLink (updated my post), maybe that could be it?

May I know what Xcode version and Device/Simulator version you're using for testing this out.
Ran similar code in Xcode 16.0(16A242d) and iPhone XR iOS 18.0(22A3354) and it works just fine
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ScrollViewReader { scrollView in
            Button("Jump to 50") {
                scrollView.scrollTo(50, anchor: .center)
            }
            
            List {
                ForEach(1...50, id: \.self) { row in
                    Text("Row \(row)")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


Edit 1 - Answer to edited question
Embedding inside Navigation Link also works.
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            NavigationLink {
                ScrollViewReader { scrollView in
                    List {
                        ForEach(1...1000, id: \.self) { row in
                            Text("Row \(row)")
                        }
                    }.onAppear {
                        scrollView.scrollTo(900, anchor: .center)
                    }
                }
            } label: {
                Image(systemName: "filemenu.and.selection").padding()
            }.buttonStyle(DefaultButtonStyle())
        }
    }
} 



Wow strange. I am on XCode 16.0, iOS 18.0 on iphone 16 Pro simulator. I do have this list in a NavigationLink (updated my post), maybe that could be it?

@DewinDell have updated the answer, seems to be working fine for me, maybe try running on a device. Simulator sometimes gives unexpected bugs.

thank you for the help, appreciate it. I was able to get it to work with a DispatchQueue.main.async

mabe List can't has ScrollerView

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
